# Mi band 3 disconnect after 1 minute using BLE

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm building an app to let the mi band 3 communicate on the phone and be able to read the data. The mi band connects but releases the connection after 1 minute. The connection is made via BluetoothGatt.

As SDK I am using https://github.com/pabloAndresSanz/MiBand-sdk, I've searched literally everywhere for a solution but haven't found anything yet, and this SDK comes with everything I need to understand how it works.

BluetoothGatt, after the minute it stays connected, calls this method (here the method log): `D/BluetoothGatt: onClientConnectionState() - status=19 clientIf=10 device=E7:02:3C:01:E8:C3`, after that, run the `close()` method and `unregisterApp()`

My problem is then to solve this connection error, I have read that it is caused by the device intentionally disconnecting with status 19 = GATT_CONN_TERMINATE_PEER_USER, but I don't know how to fix. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried using a generic BLE scanner like 'nRF Connect' for your connection? If you manage to stay connected longer it's a problem with your app

Comment: Yes, but even then it disconnects after a minute. it is more a problem between the mi band that cannot keep the connection and bluetoothgatt, in fact the mi band 3 first requires authentication, which I have and it works, but despite everything it is as if it wanted to disconnect because there is nothing else to it do.

Comment: @JuriTelloli Same is happening with me

Comment: @Kudos I resolved using this sdk https://github.com/Micallam/MiBandPulse, it's simplier to understand and has everything you need to resolve that problem of the authentication. I hope it will help :)

Comment: Thankss @JuriTelloli But i am looking for implementing in iOS.